# Items in drop down are not clickable

Tags: html, css

I did some searches on the matter but seem to receiving mixed answers and I'm not entirely sure how to go about this given my limited coding knowledge.

I downloaded a website template called Brushed by Alessio Atzeni (mentioned for easier reference). The template is fantastic but unfortunately it does not come with dropdown functionality so I looked up a couple of tutorials and have managed to create my own.

```
<div class="sticky-nav">
    <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"></a>

    <div id="logo">
        <a id="goUp" href="#home-slider" title="rando"></a>
    </div>

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="menu-nav">
            <li class="current"><a href="#home-slider">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#services">Our Services</a>
    <ul id="menu-nav-dropdown">
    <li><a href="xxx.html">Social Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx.html">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx.html">Development</a></li>

    </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#social-area">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>
```

This is the HTML for index.html for the navbar, when I hover over "services" the dropdown appears and each individual element highlights as a result of me hovering but when I click it nothing happens. However, if I right click and "open in new tab" that proper page is generated.

I chose not to include the CSS to prevent cluttering the post, but if you need any other information I'll gladly provide it as soon as possible. Does anyone know what the issue might be? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: here is the http://jsfiddle.net/tuvon83p/1/ it doesn't look good at all but I believe the functionality is there and working properly (you just need to hover over to the right to see the links because there isn't a background).

Comment: Without the CSS, this is just a bunch of links in lists, not a drop down. Reduce the HTML and CSS to the strict minimum to show your problem and post it. Providing a jsfiddle also helps.

Comment: In your fiddle, clicking on "link1"/"link2"/"link3" does open the associated URL.

Comment: Correct which confuses me a bit, but leads me to believe the issue is CSS related. I'm not too familiar with what could possible cause a conflict in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
nav ul li ul li a{
position: relative;
top:0;
left: 0;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
}
```

basically: In the navigation, locate all ul, locate all li, locate all ul, locate all li, and select the a and it should go to the unclickable and put it above all things. There may be something above it?

Comment: if something is above the `a` tag and if its preventing the  click, then even `right click-> open in new tab` will not work right?

Comment: I *believe* (meaning, I'm not sure if I did it properly) I tried this, no luck. I've edited my original post with the jsfiddle if that helps.

Thanks for the reply.